# undefined method `paginate' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I'm upgrading from Rails 4.0 to 4.1.8 and I'm getting this error "undefined method `paginate' for nil:NilClass" I updated my will_paginate gem to 3.0.7 and my will_paginate-bootstrap gem to  1.0.1 The error is in the index of my pins_controller.rb file.

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
  # GET /pins
  # GET /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.search(params[:search])
    @pins = @pins.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pins }
      # format.js
    end
  end
```

and in my view:

```
<%= will_paginate @collection, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

This all worked perfectly before upgrading and I rechecked all of the documentation to see if anything has changed about these settings above.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had two things that needed to be changed. The main issue was that I was assigning @pins twice. I had to first change the search code in my pins.rb to:

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      losearch = search.downcase
      where('lower(description) LIKE ? OR lower(artist) LIKE ? OR lower(album) LIKE ? OR lower(year) LIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.to_s.downcase}%")
    end
  end
```

Then I was receiving an error "Undefined method total_pages", so I changed my pins_controller.rb to:

```
def index
    if params[:search]
      @pins = Pin.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
    else  
      @pins = Pin.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
    end  
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pins }
      # format.js
    end
  end
```